# Data is getting download two times when I reload the page and when I click on download

Tags: php, html, csv

I created a web page for downloading the data from database in csv format but it getting download two times when I load the page and when I click on download. How can I stop the downloading when I refresh the page.

Comment: Presumably you need to write code which checks that the button has been clicked, and only then allows fetching the data. Can't help you more without seeing the related HTML and PHP...people cannot guess what solution to apply to your specific code, there can be different ways of doing this. For future reference please read the [tour] and [ask] and all about how to create a [mre] of your problem. This would make your question much clearer and more useful. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you open a new tab for download the file,  It will automatically be closed once the file is downloaded, and when you reload it will not download again